# USB microphone audio quality gets choppy after some time

Tags: audio

I use a [Fifine USB Mic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XCKGLTP) on a 2018 Macbook Pro with MacOS Monterey 12.6.1, in clamshell mode with 2 monitors connected through a Caldigit TS3 dock. After some time, coworkers on Zoom will tell me my audio is choppy and sounds like it is repeating. This seems to not be an issue with the mic, but something within MacOS because if I switch to the mic built into my webcam, it has the same problem.

If I open Quicktime and do an audio recording, the time and file size increase rapidly for some reason when using any USB mic source. See the below screen capture of this behavior. You will notice after only recording a few seconds, the length is 11m50s and the file size is 68MB.
[image: screen capture of audio issue]

If I open the computer up and do the same audio recording test using the built-in mic, there is no issue with the audio quality, time or file size.

Here is how the mic appears in Audio MIDI Setup:
[image: mic audio midi settings]

This issue is irritating and I only know it's happening when someone else tells me since I can't hear it on my end. The only solution I have found is to restart the computer and it will work for some time until it happens again. Here is what I have tried that does not work but my Quicktime audio test always has issues:

- Unplug mic, plug back in
- Unplug mic from Caldigit TS3 Dock, plug into Macbook Pro with USB-C adapter or vice-versa
- Use computer off dock with just USB mic plugged in
- Restart the coreaudiod service: `sudo pkill coreaudiod`

Hoping anyone can shed light on what causes this problem or any other fixes. Thanks!

Comment: There are potentially two different issues here - choppy audio on Zoom calls (could be network latency) and abnormally large file sizes when using USB audio (doesn’t necessarily make audio choppy).  What you want to do is start in Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting) and see if the problems persist.

Comment: Check Audio Midi Setup [apps/utilities] What are the mic's input parameters set to?

Comment: @Allan not separate issues, the audio issue in Zoom that my coworkers hear is the same thing I hear when doing the audio recording test. Restarting always fixes the problem and I wouldn't be able to use safe mode until the problem began again, unfortunately

Comment: @Tetsujin updated my original post, see the Audio MIDI Setup screenshot. Nothing I can configure there.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, looks fine. I'm slightly puzzled it doesn't know what the device is called. These things don't have drivers, they should just be standards-compliant [which would usually include what the heck the device actually is]